# How to remove DB in method onUpgrade?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite

How can i remove file with my database on SQLite in method onUpgrade?

I tried:

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);

    onCreate(db);
}
```

error: context cannot be resolved.

and second:

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    File dbFile = getDatabasePath("your_db_file_name");
    boolean deleted = dbFile.delete();

    onCreate(db);
}
```

error: The method getDatabasePath(String) is undefined for the type TestDatabase.

Comment: Now are you trying to drop the data in the database and re-create it or are you wishing to actually rename it all together?

Comment: `onUpgrade` is called with an active transaction; removing the database file there is not possible. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I would like with each new version my app remove database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your onUpgrade function you should simply run the drop table statements

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // delete our old table
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + tableName);

    // create our new table
    onCreate(db);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot delete the file as it is in use at the point this method is called.

Instead, if you really want to the delete the database run

```
File dbFile = getDatabasePath("your_db_file_name");
if(dbFile.exists() && dbFile.delete())
{
    // Create new database if that is what you want to do.
}
```

Before you actually instantiate the `DatabaseHelper` object. Without knowing the rest of your code it is hard to give a more detailed solution.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a method to clean the table and call it before you add the new values to it

```
public void delete_ALL_ROWS()
    {
        ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
        ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        String deleteSQL = "DELETE FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE;

        ourDatabase.execSQL(deleteSQL);

        ourHelper.close();
    }
```